# Ajuda com clone + autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocompletar, clone

Boa noite.

Estou usando este exemplo de autocomplete :
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Funciona como preciso... mas o problema ocorre quando vou clonar esse elemento.
Ai o autocomplete não funciona mais. Não consigo entender onde está o problema.

Poderiam me dar uma dica de como resolver isso?

Aqui o código com o problema: [autocomplete+clone](http://jsfiddle.net/qz29K/188/)

Grata

Att

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Marconi, bom dia, o código está no link do texto.